# NoSuchElementException selenium phantomjs python

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am using selenium with python and phantomjs for scheduling a job.

- Selenium-3.4.3
- python-3.3
- phantomjs-2.1.1

The code works fine using chrome ,selenium and python while it fails for `phantomjs` .

It shows the following error-

```
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Mukherjee\Desktop\phantom-js selenium\mysql.py", line 
76, in <module>
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='j_username' and 
 @id='username']")
 File "C:\Users\Rahul Mukherjee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 313, in 
find_element_by_xpath
 return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
 File "C:\Users\Rahul Mukherjee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 791, in 
find_element
'value': value})['value']
File "C:\Users\Rahul Mukherjee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in 
execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\Rahul Mukherjee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, 
 in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message:
{"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '//*[@name='j_username' 
 and @id='username']'",
 '","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-
```

Comment: Did you set the maximum size for the browser?

Comment: Share HTML or URL it never help us to detect issue

Comment: PhantomJS is no longer maintained I see lot of issues which mentioned it works in other browsers and not in PhantomJS. I would recommend moving away from it and using chrome headless if you want

Comment: Hi Thanks Tarun ,have you used chrome headless? .I never used it so suggestions please.Is it stable and works properly like headed browser?